# Interval limitations for BLE background scanning in Android AltBeacon Library?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon, scanning

I have been working with Android AltBeacon library. I've been noticing a strange behaviour where the device randomly stops scanning for an interval of say 5 secs or 10 secs. I have two devices A and B next to each other and these devices are both advertising and scanning in iBeacon format using AltBeacon library.

```
/**
 * The default duration in milliseconds of the Bluetooth scan cycle
 */
public static final long DEFAULT_FOREGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD = 1100;
/**
 * The default duration in milliseconds spent not scanning between each Bluetooth scan cycle
 */
public static final long DEFAULT_FOREGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD = 0;
/**
 * The default duration in milliseconds of the Bluetooth scan cycle when no ranging/monitoring clients are in the foreground
 */
public static final long DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
/**
 * The default duration in milliseconds spent not scanning between each Bluetooth scan cycle when no ranging/monitoring clients are in the foreground
 */
public static final long DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD = 5 * 60 * 1000;
```

These are the parameters I'm using while creating the scanner.

Hence I'm curious as to why does it stops detecting in different intervals. I don't think this has something to do on the advertising end because i keep the LocateBeacon app running in the third device just to check if the advertising is stopping in either of the other two devices.

So this issue is because of Android OS limitations or something related to the AltBeacon library. How exactly am i suppose to fix this? Because of this issue i get unnecessary `didExitRegion(..)` callbacks which messes up the use case.

Advertising device: Oppo Android version: v8.1.0 PPS: 2.2

Scanning device: OnePlus Android version: v10

**EDIT**

Following are the values I'm setting for my tx power and tx mode:

```
private int mAdvertiseMode = AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED;
private int mAdvertiseTxPowerLevel = AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_LOW;
```

Comment: Is your app in the foreground or background when this happens? What Android version to you have?  Are you using the library with a foreground service or the library in its default state?  If you run the Locate Beacon app on the same device where you see the detections dropout, does it also have 5-10 second dropouts?  What is the advertising rate of your beacon (you can use the [BeaconScope](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davidgyoungtech.beaconscanner&hl=en_US&gl=US) app to measure this with its packets per second (PPS) rating.)

Comment: @davidgyoung The app is in background with a foreground service running. The reading stops on Locate Beacon app too when i see a pause of 5-10 secs in my logs and it resumes again as soon as i see results in my logs. Have updated my question with Manufacturer and Android Version.

Comment: @davidgyoung Is there anywhere possible i could look at within the library?

Comment: The fact that both apps stop detecting at the same time suggests it is a transmitter issue.  I would use The BeafonScope app linked above to measure the packets per second (pps) from the transmitter

Comment: @davidgyoung I have already added the PPS of the transmitting device in my question.

Comment: @davidgyoung I've also added the tx power level and tx power mode in my question in case it helps. Also this isn't a behaviour I'm experiencing in any one specific devices. This behaviour has been noticed in most devices that i have tested on.

Comment: If you switch to BeaconScope as the transmitter, do you see the same dropouts?